# How to perform einsum for decomposed tensor operations?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensor, numpy-einsum, tensorly

I am trying to measure the speed up performance between `np.einsum('bcd,bce,bef->df' tensor1, tensor2, tensor1)` and `np.einsum('...->...', decomposed_tensor1, tensor2, decomposed_tensor1)` operations. The decomposition method I am using is [`tensorly.decomposition.tucker`](http://tensorly.org/stable/modules/generated/tensorly.decomposition.tucker.html#tensorly-decomposition-tucker)

However for the decomposed_tensor, tensor operations it is quite confusing to follow the indices which I should be summing over.

The below are the dimensions of the tensors and the decomposed tensors.

```
from tensorly.decomposition import tucker
import numpy as np

d1, d2, d3 = 256, 4, 12

# the tensor of interest 
tensor1 = np.random.rand(d1, d2, d3)

# a tensor with appropriate dimensions to perform operations
tensor2 = np.random.rand(d1, d2, d2)

# tensor1, tensor2, tensor1 operation
tens1Tens2tens1 = np.einsum('ilk,ilm,imp->kp', tensor1, tensor2, tensor1, optimize='optimal')

# tucker decomposition of the tensor1
rank_tucker = (8,4,2)
core, factors = tucker(tensor1, rank_tucker)
print("Core Dimension:\t\t",core.shape)
print("Factors Dimensions:\t", [f.shape for f in factors])

# decomposed_tensor1, tensor2, decomposed_tensor1
# decTens1tens2decTens1 = np.einsum('...->...', core, factors, tensor2, core, factors)
```

Out:

```
Core Dimension:      (8, 4, 2)
Factors Dimensions:  [(256, 8), (4, 4), (12, 2)]
```

Can someone guide me how should I perform this decomposed tensor and tensor operations ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this matrix decomposition?

Comment: @Ivan As I also specified in my post, I am measuring the speed-up performance of tensor decomposition. So the comparison in the speed in tensor1 @ tensor2 @ tensor1 vs decomposed_tensor@ tensor2 @ decomposed tensor, operations